# What version of .NET am I running my App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.7

I have an ASP.NET Web App which I want to build and run using .NET 4.7.1 (it used to run using .NET 4.5 or I believe so).

I have updated the Target Framework of the project to .NET Framework 4.7.1 as well as reinstalled all the NuGet dependencies using this command: **Update-Package -reinstall**

My packages.config now says for all the packages this: **targetFramework="net471"**

After building my solution, I went and opened one of the DLLs of my Web App using ILSpy and I found this:

> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null // Global type:
>    // Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred) // Runtime:
>   v4.0.30319

But at the same time, the assembly says this:

> [assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1",
>   FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.7.1")]

I am obviously missing something but I have no clue what it is. From this information, it seems I am still running on .NET 4.5 but I don't know why.

My Visual Studio version is 2017

Thanks!

Comment: "*From this information, it seems I am still running on .NET 4.5 but I don't know why*" why does it seem that? from this information it seems that you are not

Comment: Am I not? I guess what is confusing me is the fact that the Runtime says v4.0.30319

Comment: The CLR version and the framework version are 2 different things, more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Comment: I see... so I guess all the subversions of .NET 4.X will have same CLR version, correct?

Comment: I don't have time to answer this fully, however maybe someone else can fill in the blanks and scope out a formal answer to OP